# Nested Hash/Linkable Tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, hash, tabs

I am trying to get a set of hash tabs working but am running into issues when I add the nested ones. I am using [this](http://srsgores.github.io/jquery-hash-tabs/#tab1) JQuery tab plugin.

The code I have that is working for un-nested tabs is:

```
        <script>
            jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                var $tabs = $(".tab-container").hashTabs({});
            });
        </script>
        <div class="hash-tabs">
            <article class="tab-container">
                <nav>
                    <li><a href="#main-tab1">Main Tab 1</a></li>
                    <li><a  href="#main-tab2">Main Tab 2</a></li>
                </nav>
                <div>
                    <section id="main-tab1">
                        Main Tab 1 Content
                    </section>
                    <section id="main-tab2">
                        Main Tab 2 Content
                    </section>
                </div>
            </article>
        </div>
```

However, this isn't working when I add in the nested tabs:

```
        <script>
            jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                var $tabs = $(".tab-container").hashTabs({});
                var $tabs = $(".secondary-tab-container").hashTabs({});
            });
        </script>

        <div class="hash-tabs">
            <article class="tab-container">
                <nav>
                    <li><a href="#main-tab1">Main Tab 1</a></li>
                    <li><a  href="#main-tab2">Main Tab 2</a></li>
                </nav>
                <div>
                    <section id="main-tab1">
                        <div class="hash-tabs">
                            <article class="secondary-tab-container">
                                <nav>
                                    <li><a href="#secondary-tab1">Main Tab 1</a></li>
                                    <li><a  href="#secondary-tab2">Main Tab 2</a></li>
                                </nav>
                                <div>
                                    <section id="secondary-tab1">
                                        Main Tab 1 Content
                                    </section>
                                    <section id="secondary-tab2">
                                        Main Tab 2 Content
                                    </section>
                                </div>
                            </article>
                        </div>
                    </section>
                    <section id="main-tab2">
                        Main Tab 2 Content
                    </section>
                </div>
            </article>
        </div>
```

Any help on this is appreciated!

Comment: Is there an error? What does not working mean?

Comment: Sorry forgot to add that. I'm not getting a console error but when I click on one of the nested tabs it collapses all of the content and just shows the main 2 tab titles.